# How to touch inside video using expo-video-player

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo, expo-av

I am using expo-video-player and I wanted to be able to control (show or hide) a custom playbackSpeed button (that is not present on the android default player, but it is on IOS) based on the users click on the screen / video.
I did this using expo-av with a Pressable component, but because of some limitations I changed the library to the expo-video-player.

I noticed that there are some functions that appear on vs code (onTouchEndCapture and others) but they doesn't seem to work.

I already used expo-av, but my custom playbackSpeed button doesn't appear when the video is on full screen, so I changed it to the expo-video-player, but I cannot hide the button with the users touch